# Combining results of Pick and Omit on the same keys fails typecheck

Tags: typescript

Why does the following code fail to typecheck?

```
const fun = <T, S extends keyof T>(
  a: Pick<T, S>,
  b: Omit<T, S>
): T => ({ ...a, ...b })
```

I get the following error:

> Type 'Pick<T, S> & Omit<T, S>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Pick<T, S> & Omit<T, S>'.

It works when I specify the keys to Pick/Omit, but for some reason it doesn't work when it's a generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently a missing feature of TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884).  The compiler is not able to perform the higher order type analysis necessary to see that `Pick<T, K> & Omit<T, K>` should be assignable to `T` when `T` and/or `K` are generic type parameters.  For any *specific* `T` and `K` the compiler can structurally verify the equivalence, but for *generic* `T` or `K` the compiler mostly just defers evaluation. From the relevant [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884#issuecomment-448356158):

> the core problem is that an intersection of complementary subsets of a higher order type, constructed using `Pick<T, K>` or by other means, is not assignable back to that higher order type.

For now, until and unless the feature requested at microsoft/TypeScript#28884 is implemented, you'll need to use something like a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that you're sure it works (because the compiler is not sure):

```
const fun = <T, K extends keyof T>(
  a: Pick<T, K>,
  b: Omit<T, K>
) => ({ ...a, ...b } as T) // no error
```

This prevents the error, but requires you to be more careful as you have taken on some of the responsibility for maintaining type safety. If you make a mistake the compiler won't be able to catch it:

```
const notNearlyAsFun = <T, K extends keyof T>(
  a: Pick<T, K>,
  b: Omit<T, K>
) => ({ ...a } as T) // no error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzDAvDAPAFQDQwNIwCmAHlIWACYQwDWhAniHDJgHwAUAsAFAwwCGALhgAFAJbAaWXHlbYefAEbCA8gFsxUaflY8AlKlYx2AbxgA6S-1yXzimAF8B1TAYD0bmGBBEATr5BfGEBeDcBZHZ4eUEhYbygAOUJ+XwAbegBBCAAxJFQMHHwiUnIqWgYmFg4FAWFxSW1ZeV4YZRh1TXrdbgMUI1MLK0dnFndPbz8AoODAOR2gA)